# PHP open source script for a specific website

Tags: php, facebook, open-source, upload, photo

Does anyone of you ever heard about a PHP open source solution that would have these features:

- Users **login/registration** (ideally connect via *Facebook*)
- Upload photos: users can upload photos and **exchange them with administrators**.
- **No photo will be shown publicly** (only to users and admin)
- Rich backend administration with **different roles** and views on the users and their uploaded photos.

Cheers,
Nicolas.

Comment: Check out http://php.opensourcecms.com/

Comment: thank you for your link, but I've already spent a lot of time looking for the perfect solution, without success; so that's why I'm posting the question here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without finding exactly what I am looking for, I guess I just have to start everything from scratch, using a PHP framework (I'm gonna use [cakePHP](http://www.cakephp.org/) because of its large community).

Thanks everyone,
Nicolas

Answer (score 2):

http://gallery.menalto.com

but it is not a *programming* question by any means

Comment: hi, yes it is a programming question, because as I said in my post it is a specific website, which means I will have a lot to code by myself. I just don't want to waste a huge amount of time if I can start from an existing solution. Btw thanks for your answer but I'm not looking for a gallery script. The uploaded photos will not be shown on the website, but only to users.

Comment: Gallery can do all that for you, including user permissions, private galleries, the whole deal. And it's hardly a "script", the source is several megabytes.  ;)

Comment: You think so? My only concern is the "exchange" between administrators and users (a user upload a photo and an admin specific role will modify it and send it back to the user). I've never seen any script doing that kind of things, did you? Cheers, Nicolas.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should go for award-winning **[Joomla](http://www.joomla.org/)**, it has thousands of plugins for photos, user handling and more, has great admin panel as well.

Comment: hi, do you think Joomla can handle specific websites? I'm reluctant to CMS scripts because I won't publish any article on the website; it is basically a website allowing people to upload and exchanging photos with administrators (with different roles).

Comment: @Nicolas: If you don't want to publish articles, you can do so and manage photos, you will have to search for photo plugins though.

Comment: @Sarfraz: yeah I know, but most of them are slideshows, nothing about exchanging photos between admins and users, am I wrong? Cheers.

Comment: @NicolasL If you want simple gallery, you may want to go for other options :)

Comment: @Sarfraz: What other options are you talking about? Coding everything by myself? :)

Comment: @Nicolas: No, there are should be ready-made solutions out there, you will have to research a bit.

Comment: :) Yeah I know, that's what I'm doing, and why I'm asking here ;)

Answer (score 0):

In my oppinion Joomla offers nearly all of those features, excepta good photo gallery, but there's "phoca gallery", with is a very good addon and also open source afaik.

I use it on several pages, it works very fine and has a very userfriendly backend (helped me a lot at the beginning)

Comment: Phoca looks more like a photo gallery presentation than management. I don't see anything about exchanging images between users and admins. Cheers.